# cannot load such file -- mechanize.rb (LoadError) on OSX 10.6

Tags: ruby, rvm, mechanize-ruby

I have a simple script:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'mechanize'
p 'Success!'
```

When I run the script, I get:

```
/Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mechanize.rb (LoadError)
from /Users/.../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from test.rb:2:in `<main>'
```

In desperation I installed RVM and updated ruby from system 1.8.7. Yet I am still getting the same error as before I installed rvm. I am now running:

```
mute:nfg ..$ ruby -v
ruby 1.9.3p385 (2013-02-06 revision 39114) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
```

irb reports the same:

```
1.9.3p385 :001 > require 'rubygems'
 => false 
1.9.3p385 :002 > require 'mechanize'
LoadError: cannot load such file -- mechanize
from /Users/../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from (irb):2
from /Users/../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/irb:16:in `<main>'
```

I have re-installed mechanize, using sudo and without, several times from the project directory.

I have tried manually requiring the gem, along with its full path.

```
mute:nfg ..$ ruby -l ~/.gems/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize.rb
/Users/../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require': cannot load such file -- mime/types (LoadError)
from /Users/../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/lib/ruby/site_ruby/1.9.1/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /Users/../.gems/gems/mechanize-2.5.1/lib/mechanize.rb:4:in `<main>'
```

(I have tried installing mime-types, too.)

RVM lists the gem fine:

```
mute:nfg ..$ rvm all do gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
libxml-ruby (2.3.3, 1.1.2)
mechanize (2.5.1)
mime-types (1.21, 1.19)
...
```

As does gem:

```
mute:nfg ..$ gem list
*** LOCAL GEMS ***
...
libxml-ruby (2.3.3, 1.1.2)
mechanize (2.5.1)
mime-types (1.21, 1.19)
...
```

Curiously, the $GEM_PATHs `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385`, `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@global` and `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p385@project` appear mostly empty (two gems in the first, none in either of the last). However, the GUI JewelleryBox confirms that all three gemsets contain `Mechanize`.

EDIT: Here is the result of gem env:

```
RubyGems Environment:
  - RUBYGEMS VERSION: 1.8.25
  - RUBY VERSION: 1.9.3 (2013-02-06 patchlevel 385) [x86_64-darwin10.8.0]
  - INSTALLATION DIRECTORY: /Users/../.gems
  - RUBY EXECUTABLE: /Users/../.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p385/bin/ruby
  - EXECUTABLE DIRECTORY: /Users/../.gems/bin
  - RUBYGEMS PLATFORMS:
    - ruby
    - x86_64-darwin-10
  - GEM PATHS:
     - /Users/../.gems
     - /Users/../.gem
     - /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8
     - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8
     - /usr/bin
  - GEM CONFIGURATION:
 - :update_sources => true
 - :verbose => true
 - :benchmark => false
 - :backtrace => false
 - :bulk_threshold => 1000
 - :sources => ["http://gems.rubyforge.org/", "http://gems.github.com"]
 - "gemhome" => "/Users/../.gems"
 - "gempath" => ["/Users/../.gem", "/usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.8", "/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8", "/usr/bin"]
- REMOTE SOURCES:
 - http://gems.rubyforge.org/
 - http://gems.github.com
```

Can anyone help?

Comment: have you tried `rvm use 1.9.3-p385` before installing gem? also if you are in project dir run `bundle install`.

Comment: Yes, I have tried rvm use 1.9.3-p385 to no avail. bundle install tells me that bundler is not installed and to run gem install bundler. I install bundler, but then it still tells me to run gem install bundler. Are you sure bundler is a required dependency of mechanize? Would gem install mechanize just install it if it were?

Comment: can you show your `gem env`?

Comment: edited to show gem env

Answer (score 1):

your environment is set to use custom paths for gems, this confuses rubygems as you install to places which are not available in `PATH`

run `rvm get head` and carefully read the outputs, it will warn you about entries in `*gemrc` that break rubygems / RVM